# Calculus 3, contunity question, what must $c$ be for $f(x,y)$ to be continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Function $f(x,y)$ below is continuous at $(0,0)$. What must $c$ be?
>   $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
> \frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2+y^2} \ \ &\text{if} \ \ (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
> c \ \ &\text{if} \ \ (x,y)=(0,0)\\
> \end{cases}$$

This is a question presented by one of my clients I tutor. I wasn't sure at first what $c$ needs to be but thinking about it I believe $c$ must be equal to $0$ but I am not sure if that is a sufficient answer. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to compute $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$. To do that, put $t= x^2 + y^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=x^2+y^2$. Since $\lim\frac{sin(r)}{r}$ when $r$ tends to $0$ is $1$, then $f$ is continuous iff $c=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It must be $1$, by the identity $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to0} \frac{\sin\alpha}\alpha=1$.